# How to deal with tqdm / tqdm_notebook in production environment

Tags: python, dev-to-production, tqdm

we are developing algorithms using `python 3.6`, `pandas`, `numpy` and others. I'm using `jupyter` as the mayor tool for developing. We like to use `tqdm` and `tqdm_notebook` for understanding how our algorithms are doing.

Once we graduate an algorithm we want to put it into production (to do basically data processing). My question is how to deal with `tqdm`. Is there a best practice? I don't want to refactor all the scripts and remove `tqdm_notebook` everywhere. In production, the python code will run on the console, not on jupyter.

thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use this import during developpement:

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
```

You will have to only modify the import when putting in production (and not all tqdm_notebook statements).

Comment: You can also use `from tqdm.auto import tqdm`. It automatically detects whether it is used in a notebook environment, or within a console environment when the code is called as a script. See https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/tqdm/auto.py.